# Magento 2 - Update Images

Tags: magento2, product-images, import, image, import-products

I'm updating the images of my products. I'm using Import menu to do it.

I would need to replace the old image by the new. The new image is indicate in a csv file by product sku. The name of the images are different.

The problem is that the old images doesn't delete.

I want to replace the old image(old_image.jpg) by the new image(new_image.jpg)

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Check if the images are still in use, if you deactivated them in the products and still tells it's in use check every store/website

Comment: I cann't revise 2000 images by hand. I want to update the images of 2000 products from import menu.

Comment: I get it, it was just to see what was the error, if you can delete by hand in some product or gives an error too, could be a lead. But, I always had problems using import tool in magento, but if the old one don't delete you can try to backup the database and delete directly there all images url and try to import again with no images. I would bet on catalog_product_entity_media_gallery table, but not sure tho